# How to fix Property has a previous declaration Firebase In-App Messaging iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-in-app-messaging

I would like to implement the `Firebase In-App Messaging` feature in my application. Documentation is available at https://firebase.google.com/docs/in-app-messaging/get-started?platform=ios

To implement that feature I installed a library in my project using the below pod.

```
pod 'FirebaseInAppMessaging'
```

After installation, I got `Property has a previous declaration` error.

[image: error screenshot]

I don't know how to fix this issue, If anyone has an idea please let me know.

Comment: Post code as text and not as an image.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I just install the pod n get the above screenshot error. The error code is not my code, That is a library code error.

Answer (score 2):

FirebaseInAppMessaging is in beta and that needs to be acknowledged in the Podfile with something like:

`pod 'FirebaseInAppMessaging', "> 10.12-beta"`

Comment: You save my day. Thanks a lot for an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove from Podfile and add by packages:

target -> file -> add Packages -> search url => https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk.git -> add Package

[image]